# After clicking a button Page is loaded but displaying white blank screen (refused to display in a frame) - Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, ui-automation, cypress

I am in a situation where the page is loaded after clicking a **button**, but displaying a **white blank screen**.

**Console Log error**
i am getting an error

**Refused to display '' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `"chromeWebSecurity": true` if it is marked false in your `cypress.json` file

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off *Content Security Policy* in Chrome using the extension [Disable Content-Security-Policy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en)

Then you load the extension in Chrome as explained in https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide.html.